# How to render particular template from other module in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, helper

viewRenderer helper allows to render templates from the same controller's actions directory, is it possible to render template from another module?

Edit: actually I found renderBySpec method in ViewRenderer but it seems it doesn't consider module param while building path, is there any other solution besides this?

Comment: Yes, see http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.viewrenderer

Answer (score 0):

In my projects, when I need to setup a different layout than default one then in my init function of Controller I set the correct layout. Like this:

```
public function init()
{
    $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('different-layout');
}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: actually I need to render similar error messages from different modules

Comment: Could you put some examples about what you really want?